# Rails Association Bug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, model-associations

I am getting ***NoMethodError in SitesController#index undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass*** in my Salesman index view and cannot find the culprit.

I have a simple rails app with the following tables: Customer, Salesman and Invoice.

In the index view for the customer table I have the following call:

`<% @customers.each do |customer| %>
    <%= customer.name %></td>
    <%= customer.address %>
    <%= customer.salesman.name %>
<% end %>`

This is the call that results in the undefined method ´name´ listed above. I made sure the salesman table has a salesman_id foreign key in the customer table. Also, I made the respective association in the models:

`class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :salesman
     has_many :invoices
end`

`class Salesman < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :customers
end`

I tested the `customer.salesman.name` call in the console and it works flawlessly. The show view for the customer has an exact call like this one and it also works. The only way I can make the customer index pass is by replacing `customer.salesman.name` to `customer.salesman_id` returning only the id.

Thank you for your time here.

```
***schema.rb*** 

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150325172212) do
create_table "customers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "address"
    t.datetime "created_at",               null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",               null: false
    t.integer  "salesman_id"
  end
create_table "invoices", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "date"
    t.string   "fid"
    t.integer  "salesman_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
    t.string   "address"
  end
create_table "salesmen", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "name"
    t.string   "address""
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
  end 

***controllers***

**customer**

Class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_customer, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  # GET /customers
  # GET /customers.json
  def index
    @customers = Customer.all
  end
  # GET /customers/1
  # GET /customers/1.json
  def show
  end
  # GET /customers/new
  def new
    @customer = Customer.new
  end
  # GET /customers/1/edit
  def edit
  end
  # POST /customers
  # POST /customers.json
  def create
    @customer = Customer.new(customer_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @customer.save
        format.html { redirect_to @customer, notice: 'Customer was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @customer }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @customer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
  # PATCH/PUT /customers/1
  # PATCH/PUT /customers/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @customer.update(customer_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @customer, notice: 'Customer was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @customer }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @customer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
  # DELETE /customers/1
  # DELETE /customers/1.json
  def destroy
    @customer.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to customers_url, notice: 'Customer was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_cliente
      @cliente = Cliente.find(params[:id])
    end
    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def customer_params
      params.require(:customer).permit(:name, :address, :salesman_id)
    end
end

***salesman***

class SalesmenController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_salesman, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  # GET /salesmans
  # GET /salesmans.json
  def index
    @salesmen = Salesman.all
  end
  # GET /salesmans/1
  # GET /salesmans/1.json
  def show
  end
  # GET /salesmans/new
  def new
    @salesman = Salesman.new
  end
  # GET /salesmans/1/edit
  def edit
  end
  # POST /salesmans
  # POST /salesmans.json
  def create
    @salesman = Salesman.new(salesman_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @salesman.save
        format.html { redirect_to @salesman, notice: 'Salesman was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @salesman }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @salesman.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
  # PATCH/PUT /salesmans/1
  # PATCH/PUT /salesmans/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @salesman.update(salesman_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @salesman, notice: 'Salesman was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @salesman }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @salesman.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
  # DELETE /salesmans/1
  # DELETE /salesmans/1.json
  def destroy
    @salesman.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to salesmans_url, notice: 'Salesman was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_salesman
      @salesman = Salesman.find(params[:id])
    end
    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def salesman_params
      params.require(:salesman).permit(:name, :address)
    end

**invoice**

class InvoicesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_invoice, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  # GET /invoices
  # GET /invoices.json
  def index
    @invoices = Invoice.all
  end
  # GET /invoices/1
  # GET /invoices/1.json
  def show
    @invoice = Invoice.find(params[:id])
    @ordenes = @invoice.ordenes
  end
  # GET /invoices/new
  def new
    @invoice = Invoice.new
  end
  # GET /invoices/1/edit
  def edit
  end
  # POST /invoices
  # POST /invoices.json
  def create
    @invoice = Invoice.new(invoice_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @invoice.save
        format.html { redirect_to @invoice, notice: 'Invoice was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @invoice }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @invoice.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
  # PATCH/PUT /invoices/1
  # PATCH/PUT /invoices/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @invoice.update(invoice_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @invoice, notice: 'Invoice was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @invoice }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @invoice.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
  # DELETE /invoices/1
  # DELETE /invoices/1.json
  def destroy
    @invoice.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to invoices_url, notice: 'Invoice was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_invoice
      @invoice = Invoice.find(params[:id])
    end
    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def invoice_params
      params.require(:invoice).permit(:date, :fid, :name, :address, :salesman_id)
    end
end
```

-davefogo

Comment: The error could be with `customer.name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following  to your views instead of what you currently have`<%= customer.salesman.name if customer.salesman %>`

This will ensure that you're not calling `name` when customer doesn't have a salesman.

Comment: Thank you neo this worked out! Why though? I am not understanding the logic why it was failing?

Comment: You have a nil salesman somewhere, when you call name of nil, you get that error

Comment: Thank you neo!  Actually found the nil and corrected the code.

Comment: The Railsway is using `#try` in such scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<% @customers.each do |customer| %> 
  <%= customer.name %> 
  <%= customer.address %> 
  <%= customer.salesman.try(:name) %> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: Worked also! Why was it failing and now works? Thanks Sharvy.

Comment: You have some customers who do not have salemans. For that particular Customer, `customer.saleman` will return `nil`, okay? So, when you are trying to get the `name` of `nil` by `customer.salesman.name` (= nil.name), it raises `NoMethodError`. So Rails provides you `#try` for such scenarios. Now if you do `nil.try(:name)`, it will return `nil` instead of raising exception. Got it?

Comment: @davefogo, did you get it?

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
<% @customers.each do |customer| %>
  <% Rails.logger.debug "\n\n#{@customers} has a nil customer in it\n\n" if customer.nil? %>
  <% Rails.logger.debug "\n\nCustomer #{customer.id} has no salesman for [#{customer.salesman_id}]\n\n" if customer.salesman.nil? %>
  <%= customer.name %>
  <%= customer.address %>
  <%= customer.salesman.name %>
<% end %>
```

...and then check your logs after hitting the index.